# How does Google Chrome automatically add search URI's to its ‘Other search engines’?

Tags: google-chrome

In *Google Chrome* settings → Manage search engines → **Other search engines**, you may see lots of URI's, of various websites, for searching. Most of them were **automatically** added by *Google Chrome*. So here comes the question: **how** and **where** does *Chrome* catch those URI's? Does it consider `<input type="search">`? Does it obtain them from `<meta>` tags?

[image: **Other search engines**]

Comment: @JoshLee Right, this question is a duplicate and I got the way thanks to you. And also I've just gotten to know that the URI bar is called an _omnibox_. Thank you so much.

Comment: Voted to `close` it.